# I need an annotation tool to label many images to create a database

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, annotations

i need a tool that can read a list of images one by one and in each one i want to be able to highlight the damage and then save the processed image in a file .At the same time i want to be able to label the image (damage position) and store both name of the image and its label in a csv file.The csv file should contain at the end all the names of the processed images and their labels

Comment: What exactly do you mean by highlighting the damage? Is it some king of an area in the image, that needs to be highlighted?

Comment: highlight the damage means i want tjust to capture the precised damaged part of the image